# How do I stop the user waiting for a long time to get a location fix?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, location-provider

I am building a GPS Android application which gets the nearest places based on the user's current location.

This is what my application does:

- Check if GPS or Network is available
- If neither is available then don't do anything. Else, we first check for GPS if it's there, if not then we check for Network.
- After using one of them, we get the current location and then send it off to the server.
- Once we retrieve data from the server and update the UI, we stop listening for further location updates. Once is enough, until they press the refresh button which starts this again.

What I hope to do:

- If GPS or network fails to retrieve a location, for example, 2 minutes, then we switch providers. We don't want the user to wait too long.
- It would also be nice to be able to use both providers and then get the most accurate from that. I've taken a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html and I saw the isBetterLocation method. How would I integrate this method in my application? I'm having trouble understand how, where and when it should be called. I assume that the isBetterLocation() requires me to call both Network and GPS at the same time. It would be nice for my application to listen to both for accuracy. How do I do this? What if one of them isn't available?

Here's parts of my code:

```
if(!GPSEnabled && !networkEnabled)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: This application requires a GPS or network connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    if(GPSEnabled)
    {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    else if(networkEnabled)
    {
        System.out.println("Getting updates from network provider");
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

This is the `onLocationChanged` method. I get the lat/lng values and then send them off to my server and then do appropriate stuff with it.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    //Get coordinates
    double lat = (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("MainActivity", "got location: " + lat + ": " + lng);
    //get nearest locations
    new GetLocations().execute(SharedVariables.root + SharedVariables.locationsController + SharedVariables.getNearestMethod + lat + "/" + lng); 

    // Zoom in, animating the camera after the markers have been placed
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10));
    System.out.println("lat = " + lat + ", lng = " + lng);

     //Stop listening for updates. We only want to do this once. 
     locManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

Comment: You've seen this?: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html. And the protips sample app?: https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/

Comment: The network provider is inaccurate, but it returns  the location in less than a second

Comment: Hi Reno, Thanks. I understand that GPS and Network differ in terms of accuracy and speed and this brings me to my question, how do I implement a feature whereby, if either providers are available, I get the location based on one of the providers, preferably GPS because it is the most accurate, then if a fix is not found after x amount of time, I try to switch over to Network provider, if it is switched on.

Answer (score 0):

Either using GPS or the network, you can't drastically reduce the eventual waiting time to get your location.

Both of these location methods have their disadvantages and advantages:

- GPS usually takes a longer time to know your location, because finding and calibrating GPS satellites is a tremendous task (finding *at least* 3 correctly-aligned satellites is required). On top of that, add the eventual obstructing objects/environment blocking the signals. Unless you enable GPS before/when your app starts, wait is mandatory. **On the other side**, you get a fine-grained location.
- If you only need a rough location, using the network is a solution: it returns data in a few seconds. **However** the precision of the location varies depending on the available/used networks; I don't have any practical examples, but I guess the precision can *greatly* vary. GPS will *ALWAYS* have a better-grained location than network.

Understand there is **no predefined choice**. Anything depends on what your app does with this data.

Use GPS if available, while making the location request to the network, and fall back to network if there is no GPS device. Then take either:

- the first-coming result if you just need a location
- the preferred result if you want the most precise data

> If GPS or network fails to retrieve a location, for example, 2 minutes, then we switch providers. We don't want the user to wait too long.

In both cases, do not make a fallback timer: you'll just lengthen the waiting time in the case where the first provider fails; so do both request at the same time, unless the android API does not permit asynchronous location requests.

Comment: Thanks. As I stated before in my reply to Reno's comment, I understand the differences between GPS and the network providers. As we have both alluded to in my question and your answer about using both requests simultaneously, I wanted to know how this would be implemented. How do we pick the most accurate location when we use two providers? And also, in the last part of my question, what do we do if one of the providers is not enabled?

Comment: As I said, GPS will _always_ have the best precision. But unless you get to know how precise a network is (by requesting its precision; or caching the precision of this specific network when GPS is also available (make the difference between the 2 providers)), it is not possible to determine which provider should be chosen. Averaging the values of the different location providers maybe?